# Is it possible to find the first (Subversion) commit of the use of a certain function in a certain file?

Tags: svn

I would like to know when (in which revision) I used a certain function within a certain file for the first time. I don't know

- in which files to look for what and
- which format these files have.
  Thanks for any help
  M'

So far I did not try anything, sorry.

Comment: sounds like the kind of stuff that `svn blame` is used for. If it were git, i would also suggest to use `git log -Ssomething -- filename`, don't know if there's something like that in svn.

Answer (score 1):

Using `svn blame` is certainly a good starting point. However, it shows the *last* time a line was changed, not the first time.

I would propose something along the lines:

- Get last changed revision using `svn blame`. Let's call it revision `R`.
- See if the line was added or just changed in `R` with `svn diff -c R`
- If it was only changed, proceed with `svn blame --revision R-1` (or the shorthand `svn blame FILE@R-1`).
- Rinse, repeat.

For more documentation, refer to [blame in the red bean book](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html).

Answer (score 0):

The hint by eftshift0 was really helpful: Doing
svn blame 
produced a list of all lines involved in all revisions. Then it was just a matter to look up the function I was interested in.